# Comprobar si un archivo es un fichero de dispositivo

Tags: linux, bash

El ejercicio consiste en evaluar los archivos que contiene un directorio según sean:

- Directorios
- Ejecutables
- De dispositivo
- Archivos regulares

Mi código de momento es este:

```
    # Clasificamos el contenido del directorio
    # Contadores:
    d=0
    e=0
    t=0
    dv=0

    # Recorremos el directorio actual
    for entry in *
    do
    echo "$entry"

            # Comprobamos si es un directorio
            if [ -d "$entry" ]
            then
                ((d = d + 1))
            fi

            # Comprobamos si es ejecutable
            elif [ -x "$entry" ]
            then
                ((e = e + 1))
            fi

            # Comprobamos si es un fichero de texto (regular)
            elif [ -f "$entry" ]
            then
                ((t = t + 1))
            fi

    done
```

He estado probando, y de momento va bien, pero no encuentro la manera de comprobar si un archivo es un fichero de dispositivo (/dev)

Comment: -b para comprobar si es un block device
-c para comprobar si es un character device

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez Podrías explicar la diferencia entre block device y character device (soy nuevo en shellscript, lo pregunto para saber cual usar) Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hay distintos tipos de archivos de dispositivo.

desde el bash puedes usar:

- -b para comprobar si es un block device
- -c para comprobar si es un character device

como ambos son archivos de dispositivo, deverias de usar el operador logico y[&&]

```
elif [ -b "$entry" ] && [-c "$entry" ];
then
   ((dv = dv + 1))
fi
```

[Sobre los Archivos de dispositivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_dispositivo)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta